# Server software or hardware question closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question

My question https://superuser.com/questions/327971/is-the-server-hardware-or-software
was close on the same day citing wikipedia quotes that Server can be both hardware and software hence this is not a real question

Since then wikipedia answer has changed and it now emphasis more on server being software. Should we be closing question here just because there is citation available in wikipedia but that is not clear to OP or he does not agree on it or he need more authoritative answer?

I am asking this question after so many months passed by because this is my 2nd question with more number of hits. Why close question which people find interested and are on topic?

Comment: Better suited for http://english.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

The reason for closure is a bit misleading here. I would close it as *not constructive*:

> […] this question will likely **solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion**.

The fact that a question is related to computer hardware or software doesn't automatically make it on-topic, because there are several other reasons for questions being closed—A shopping recommendation is always about computer stuff but still considered off-topic.

After all, the answer to your question is "it depends", and there's no point in going around over definitions, when there truly is no one answer. Remember that Super User is not a forum, and discussion about a topic is *not* what we want.

Comment: IMO if given a chance this question is totally answerable, it is not argumentative. It just needs someone knowledgable to answer the question. If I were to argue about, what will I argue about? How many points of view do think exist in this case? 2, 4, 8, infinite? A question is arable if every can come with *his own* argument.

Comment: We all know a [Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server) is the person who brings you food. ;)

Comment: @Dave everything you listed there could be referred to as "server" as always context dictates the definition.  http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/server

Comment: @Dave You don't need to be knowledgeable. Anyone can look up the word "server" in the dictionary and start a flamewar about when or how it should be used. *> If I were to argue about, what will I argue about?* – exactly that. You say that you *found the "Server" is a actually a software* – and what happens if I tell you that we ordered some new rack servers for our institute? Et cetera.

Answer (score 3):

That was a question about dictionary definitions and depends on what you're asking about and in what context.

It could be software, if you're asking in terms of software. Or hardware if asking in that realm. The answer really depends on who, where and how.

The secondary point of why it may be confusing is grounds for conjecture as you then have people citing all sides of the argument for where the definition is heading, where it is now, and what it means to be applied so liberally across the computing world.

Comment: I am afraid dictionary definition of Server is something entirely different [check here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/server) and it was never asked in that context. It is applied through out computer world and superuser would be a great forum to clarify this.

Comment: The link explains both uses in software and hardware. Yes.

Comment: The fact that this is computer related and on topic should not be closed. This is my point.

Comment: It wasn't closed as off topic. It was closed for the reasons outlined above.